# Using php $_SESSION in sql statements

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to update a table in my database. This is the code I have so far:

```
$query =
"UPDATE user
SET name='$name', pword='$pword', email='$email', address='$address', city='$city', state='$state', zip='$zip'
WHERE uname ='" . $_SESSION['uname'] . "'";
```

My page renders correctly but the table is never updated with the new data. I assume it's because the code can't figure our the whole $_SESSION part of this argument. Any ideas?

I'm trying to add this code to populate the $_SESSION['uname'] part of this...

```
$uname = $_SESSION["sname"]["uname"];
```

I'm trying to figure out where the sname came from myself...

Comment: are you callign session_start() at somewhere prior in this script?

Comment: @echochamber I sure am. I have a lot of php surrounding this, however it isn't relevant to the issue I'm having.

Comment: don't *assume* `echo $query`, will tell you.

Comment: Like Dagon said, just output the query or run it and you will see the error.

Comment: @Dagon this is the output for the query when I submit the edit form: `UPDATE user SET name='Lindsay', pword='admin', email='admin@gmail.com', address='1234 Musical Blvd', city='Tempe', state='AZ', zip='85281' WHERE uname =''`

Comment: You might have some ` in your variables,we cant tell from the code you posted.The syntax is correct,now if there is anything in that SESSION is another question.

Comment: Is this `WHERE uname =''` ok ?

Comment: if you want that condition,yes.Are you really trying to update where uname is empty?

Comment: @Mihai I'm trying to update where uname is equal to the uname of the user that is currently in the session. That's why the code (not the query output) says `WHERE uname ='" . $_SESSION['uname'] . "'";`

Comment: Assumption based failure. @Dagon already suggested it and @Glavić pinpointed it: `$_SESSION['uname']` is empty.

Comment: Your SESSION is empty,add the code the deals with that in your question.

Comment: @Mihai how do I go about populating the $_SESSION? I have the `uname`s stored in a table.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of problems with this. It's very vulnerable to SQL injection, to begin with.

But the reason it's not updating your table is that `$query` is just a string.  You don't show a MySQL, MySQLi, or PDO connection anywhere, and you don't show that you're executing the statement on a connection.

Based on your comment above, the problem is that `$_SESSION['uname']` is either an empty string or undefined. Your problem isn't in this query; it's in some other part of your code.

Comment: I have the whole thing set to connect. I used this code to create table entries, but right now I'm trying to edit this code to edit the entries for a different page.

Comment: I got the same feeling, more or less, but I can't honestly say that this code snippet is so vulnerable. We don't see any external input being used. Even $_SESSION is something you manage yourself completely . So as far as we can tell, every variable used might be escaped properly.

Comment: See the above edit. @GolezTrol: If 100% of the data comes from the OP, it *might* be safe. But if OP ever gets any of this data from another source, this is a bad way to do it. Even a simple entry like `"Joe O'Brien"` would break it, as would `"Joe ';DROP TABLE user; -- '"`.

Comment: `$_SESSION` is NOT vulnerable to SQL injection from user space, assuming of course that you don't do something silly like directly put some user-input value directly into it.

Comment: Who says I'm talking about $_SESSION?  There are 7 other variables being concatenated right into the query!

Comment: @EdCottrell It's not perfect, and I would prefer use of PDO and parameters as well, but 'back in the says' when I didn't, I would escape the variables before I put them in a string. So if I was to post this snippet you would also not see that I escaped them. The comment about vulnerability usually applies to situations where people put $_GET and $_POST values directly into a query. Maybe that happens here as well, but we can't tell, so I felt the need to expound your point of view, especially because it was about half your answer before you edited it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

$query = "SELECT uname FROM mytable WHERE somecondition LIMIT 1" or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

$result = $link->query($query);

while($row = mysqli_fecth_assoc($result)) {
  $user=$row["uname"] ;
} 
$_SESSION['uname']=$user;

?>
```

Here is some basic php to get the user from DB into `SESSION`,adapt it to your db. Dont forget `session_start`.